# c# reference on programatically created control

Tags: c#, reference, controls

I am using WinForms and programatically added TabControl with TabPages. In one of these TabPage is DataGridView. So lets say that I have `public void create_Tab_Control();`.

Now I want to add a row to this DataGridView by another `public void add_row();`.

Is there a simplier way to do this without using Controls.Find? The problem is, that Visual Studio has no idea about this DataGridView name, so I would need to create some reference to `create_Tab_Control()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hold a reference in a class-level variable when you create the `DataGridView` control, and then use that variable to add the rows:

```
//Class-level variables
private DataGridView _gridView;

public void create_Tab_Control()
{
    //Logic to create the Tabs
    _gridView = new DataGridView();

    //Add the DataGridView to the TabControl
}

public void add_row()
{
    //Add the row(s) to the DataGridView
    _gridView.Rows.Add("column 1", "column 2");
}
```

Comment: No problem, glad to help.  If this answers your question, please mark it as answered to close the loop.  Thanks.